# Caliburn Micro MVVM INotifyPropertyChange

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

So I'm using Cliburn Micro and i have a Bindablecollection, lets call it users.

```
        public BindableCollection<UserModel> Users
    {
        get { return _users; }
        set
        {
            _users = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Users);

        }
    }
```

Now this is linked to a datagrid with two columns FirstName and LastName
In another panel the selected item of the datagrid gets set

```
                <DataGrid x:Name="AllUsers" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="5"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                  IsReadOnly="True" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridUsers}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action DoubleClickUser()]">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" Width="*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Then i've created a TextBoxFirstName and i only set the value if its not null

```
                            <DockPanel>
                            <Label x:Name="LabelFirstName" Width="80" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFAD231F" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" FontSize="12" >First Name</Label>
                            <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxFirstName" Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="{Binding 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=TextBoxFirstName,
                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource RoundedTextBox}" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode"/>
                        </DockPanel>
```

My Error Validation over the textbox is,

```
        public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;
            if (columnName == "TextBoxFirstName")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxFirstName))
                {
                    result = "Please enter a First Name";
                }
                else
                {
                    SelectedUser.FirstName = TextBoxFirstName;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedUser);
                }

            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Now I know SelectedUser.FirstName is updated as if i set another textbox databinding to SelectedUser.FirstName it updates as expected, but its not updating the Datagrid when i change it?
but if i update the value in the secondtextbox (the one with the binding SelectedUser.FirstName) it does update the datagrid,

AnyIdeas??
Basically i only want to update the datagrid if the value in the textbox passes the validation.
Assume i don't want to edit the values in the datagrid itself.

Driving me mad I know it must be with the way it notifies but i can't get it to work and im fairly new to c# and MVVM and WPF any help would be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: Does UserModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Wes If you mean the selecteduser then yes it does, 
            public UserModel SelectedUser
        {
            get { return _selectedUser; }
            set
            {
                _selectedUser = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedUser);

            }
        }

Comment: No I meant on the UserModel class not the SelectedUser property.

Comment: Sorry im new to this, how is setting inotify in the usermodel different to setting it where i have set it? isn't MVVM to seperate your model data from the code that interacts with the View? my point is its notifying the other textbox i set to SelectedUser.FirstName but isn't notifying the datagrid bound to the exact same SelectedUser.FirstName?
Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to NotifyOfPropertyChange on FirstName instead of SelectedUser. Preferably you should do this in the FirstName setter.

Comment: I've tried                     else
                    {

                        SelectedEmployee.FirstName = TextBoxFirstName;
                        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedEmployee.FirstName);

                    }
And it still doesn't work?

Comment: You need to raise property changed from inside the user object. Try raising property changed in the LastName setter whenever LastName is updated. And of course your user object needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: If your datagrid is bound to a collection of UserModel objects, then UserModel must implement INotifyPropertyChanged and each property that can be changed must raise the PropertyChanged event passing the name of that property. Otherwise the datagrid text column will not be notified of any changes.

Answer (score 1):

So, The way I was implementing the IDataError was wrong, you don't need to set the the value in an else statement.
[The way i should have implemented it.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f8cc491c-8975-4494-906b-593970dcaeca/idataerrorinfo-and-long-binding-path?forum=wpf)

Should have used it in my model not in the viewmodel.

Also My Model looks like this,

```
namespace App.Models
{
public class ConfigModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private bool _showConfig;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool ShowConfig
    {

        get { return this._showConfig; }
        set
        {
            this._showConfig = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ShowConfig");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help from Wes and Mark for pointing me in the right direction.